# how can i add test-balance to stripe test account for testing API integration

Tags: stripe-payments

There is any way to add balance to stripe account in test-mode immediately for API integration testing?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Allow charging 'Balance' to test account urgently that developer can test stripe integration

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('Your_Test_SK');
$stripe->charges->create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => 'tok_bypassPending',
  'description' => 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs)',
]);
```

use `tok_bypassPending` as value of `source` charge test account balance urgently
**API Documentation:** https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create
**Test Token Documentation:** https://stripe.com/docs/testing?lang=php#cards-responses
Move to 'Tokens' Tab, first will be this token
**Token Documentation Screensot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/55otJ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do one more thing to add funds to your test account.

1. Just login into your stripe account
2. Go to Payments and click on Create your first payment or the new payment button.
3. it will open up a popup window, here you can fill any amount along with the card number: 4000000000000077
4. Click on Create payment button and that's it